# Is there a way to start multiple instances of the same program during startup?

Tags: windows-7, boot

Where I work I need to have at least three instances of the same program up.

I've only been able to get one to open during startup. While its not a big deal to open them manually, it would be nice if they would fire up when I have to start/restart my computer. The Operating System is Windows 7.

Comment: Try to put shorcut of your program there: %systemdrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: **One** shortcut?

Comment: You can use a script (e.g. AutoIt) in the startup folder that executes *Run* or *ShellExecute* three times.

Comment: Does the program in question allow multiple instances to be run?  "I've only been able to get one to open during startup."  What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: you could create a batch file that opens the program three times and then run that instead

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Start Menu, click the search box and type 'Run' to access the Run program box. Once you've accessed 'Run', enter in the following line:

***shell:startup***

You'll be taken to the Windows Startup file. Add the shortcuts of the program you'd like to auto-boot. If you'd like to run multiple instances of the program, left-click on the shortcut, hover the cursor over 'Send To', and select 'Desktop (Shortcut)'. You'll need to send as many shortcuts as you need (-1), and move all of them to the Startup file. The next time you boot up your computer, the programs selected, and as many windows of that program, will automatically start.
**`I've tested this method, and it works completely.`**